# Large DF to plot

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, seaborn, data-visualization

I have a large df to plot (couple of millions of rows, 8 columns, obtained by concatenation of several files).
I want to plot several graphs using facet, in order to have complete view on data:
'''

```
rp = sns.relplot(data=df, 
                 x='zscore', 
                 y='%',
                 col='Nr',
                 row ="Support",
                 style="Metal",
                 kind='line')
```

'''

I tried both in Seaborn and Plotly Express but time to build this graphs is just too important, more than one hour on my laptop.
What can I improve, optimize, i order to speed graph creation?

Thank you!
PS. I do am a newbie in Python and programming ;)

Comment: Why do you need all of it? I'm not sure you will realistically get much useful information from plotting a couple million points. Can you not take a random sample?

Comment: To be honest, i dont'know how : didn't see documentation on that on seaborn... how can I graph a random sample without impacting visual representation of data distribution, please?

Comment: I think I need to look on pandas not on Seaborn... I will try this: DataFrame.sample(n=None, frac=None, replace=False, weights=None, random_state=None, axis=None)

Comment: [This][1] might help you get started. You should start with a small sample size and increase it until you are comfortable with the time taken. I'm not an expert on the specifics of sampling distribution vs. population distribution, however.


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53950607/fastest-way-to-sample-pandas-dataframe

Comment: thank you, i'll go with that!

Comment: just came back to say it works, and also, that I discover [DataExplore](https://openresearchsoftware.metajnl.com/articles/10.5334/jors.94/), nice tool to explore pandas dataframes